# Using piler with express 3 and nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, piler

I want to run Express 3.3.x with its default implementation.
Express uses its routes module, so what I have to do, if JS and CSS is accessible by any view in any route?

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var piler = require('piler');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var config = require('./config');

var app = exports.app = express();
var js =  piler.createJSManager();
var css = piler.createCSSManager();
var srv = require('http').createServer(app);

// all environments
js.bind(app,srv);
css.bind(app,srv);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

js.addUrl("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js");

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

/**
 * Routes
 */
var routes = require('./routes');
app.get('/', routes.index);

srv.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

In the example of piler:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index.jade", {
        layout: false,
        js: js.renderTags(),
        css: css.renderTags()
    });
});
```

This works. But I have

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

So what I have to do, that js.renderTags() works in every view?

Comment: I didn't get the question, what's the problem with jade templates here that do not allow to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to pass variables to render, you can use `res.locals`

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  res.locals.layout= false;
  res.locals.js= js.renderTags();
  res.locals.css= css.renderTags();
  next();
});
```

Use this before your router but don't overwrite your locals (`res.locals={...}`)